# How to access age value from the array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const data = [{
"hello":'thameem',
"age":24
},
{
"hello":'thameem',
"age":25
}];
console.log(data);
```

I need all age values

Comment: In which format do you need those values? Like `data[0].age`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let data = [{ "hello":'thameem', "age":24 }, { "hello":'thameem', "age":25 }];

// will give you an array to ages
data = data?.map(item => item.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to create an array

```
const ages = data.map((d) => d.age);
console.log(ages);
```

If you don't need new array and just want to access the property, you may use `forEach`

```
data.forEach((d) => {
  // do something with your data
}
```